# What is the best method for two way binding and disabling editable text fields in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

For POCOs with lots of fields I find it really convenient to have a simple form/component binding structure like this

< input type="text" bind="@Person.FirstName" />

< input type="text" bind="@Person.LastName" />

< input type="text" bind="@Person.Address" />

Where I then have save or create new buttons/events to deal with object at a time situations. In other words the entire object is bound to an editable component making life super easy to bring objects from the DB for editing and back into the db.

What I find annoying are situations where I have to both display an object's details but make sure parts of it are locked/un-editable based on certain conditions. Let's say I can't change LastName for some business logic reason. This:

< input type="text" bind="@Person.LastName" disabled="@somecondition" />

is unsafe as users can potentially inspect the page, modifying the disabled flag and still cause the two way binding to be enabled and changes overwritten in the existing save event. The workarounds I find are annoying e.g., you can use if code blocks to switch between textboxes and plain-text binding, or you just do all the business logic in the event which introduced more logic for error reporting.

Here is a compromise that I think "works":

if(some_protective_condition) { < input type="text" bind="@Person.Address" /> }

else { < span>@Person.Addressv< /span>}

If I understand correctly most of these workarounds essentially play with the DOM or some aspect of visibility ensuring the editable control does not get rendered. What is the coding pattern would you guys use for these situations of interface level locking?

EDIT/TLDR: Looking for the best/safe least code pattern to maintain two-way binding, display a value and make it editable/non-editable in certain situations.

Suggestions welcome as I am trying to build good solid long term habits.

Tried several techniques. Looking for the best option if I have missed something.

Comment: I would just go with disabled. However I would also in the validation of the inputs check the conditions again within a repository service. You should never trust a web UI

Comment: I would create a wrapper component to encapsulate the extra functionality you want.  I'll add some example component code as an answer if you want?  It won't be exactly what you want but will give you some ideas and direction.

Comment: You do not have direct control over the user's client browser.  For all you know, it's not Chrome, but some hackware that allows him to easily modify the DOM.  Both of the methods you described are fine (disabling an input on a bool, or using the bool to display simple text.  Normally I don't recommend altering `get;set;` on bound items, but this time, checking a bool and simply not setting the value if the component is disabled should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'Blazor Way' to integrate business rules into your views is to use AuthorizeView...

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="CanEditAddress">
    <Authorized>
        < input type="text" bind="@Person.Address" />
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        < span>@Person.Addressv< /span>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

The docs show how to populate authorization policies using cascading parameters...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter

If your rules are not really 'business rules' but are 'presentation rules' (like your forms have an edit mode vs a display mode) then the above pattern is still a good way to go.  That is, I would create a class named 'PresentationView' that is the equivalent of AuthorizationView but for presentation rules.

Answer (score 0):

> is unsafe as users can potentially inspect the page, modifying the
> disabled flag and still cause the two way binding to be enabled and
> changes overwritten in the existing save event.

I think I found the best way to handle this. Take into consideration your question:

> What is the best method for two way binding and disabling editable
> text fields in Blazor?

Create a component that does the two way binding using `InputBase` and have a parameter `IsReadOnly`. When `IsReadOnly` is true the component renders an input with out two way binding using the `value`. Otherwise, the component is rendered with two-way binding using `@bind`.

```
@if (!IsReadOnly)
{
    <input type="text" @bind="@CurrentValue" />
}
else
{
     <input type="text" value="@CurrentValue" disabled />
}


@code {
     [Parameter] public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Now when the client inspects the page and removes the disabled attribute the value is not bound, thus not updated.